# Apple Mach-O Linker error ("duplicate symbol")

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to compile my game and an error that shouldn't be coming up is.

These are the files for my class:

Circle.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Circle : NSObject
{

}
@property (readwrite, assign) CGPoint Center;
@property (readwrite, assign) float Radius;

+ (Circle *) CircleMakeFromCenter:(CGPoint)center radius:(float)radius;

@end
```

Circle.m:

```
#import "Circle.h"

@implementation Circle
@synthesize Center;
@synthesize Radius;

+ (Circle *) CircleMakeFromCenter:(CGPoint)center radius:(float)radius{
    Circle *c = [[Circle alloc] init];
    c.Center = center;
    c.Radius = radius;

    return c;
}

@end
```

It is bring up an error saying that Radius is a duplicate symbol.

Why would it bring up this error?

Comment: You should include the text of the link step. It can show where the duplicate symbols are from. It's possible you added your .h file to your compile phase--that can cause this to happen I believe.

Comment: I cleaned and rebuilt it, the error still comes up. How do I tell if I added it to my compile phase?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most common reason for this sort of error in Objective-C is that you have put this in one of your files accidentally:

```
#import "Circle.m"
```

when you should have put this:

```
#import "Circle.h"
```

Comment: OMG I just spent an hour overlooking a .m instead of a .h THANK YOU!

Comment: Yeah, Xcode offers to autocomplete `#import` with both `.h` and `.m` files, so it's easy to make this mistake.

Comment: Thank you!!!! JAgoston - you should have just searched for .m" worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were really two different implementation files; I was playing with localization and I accidentally created two different .m files for different locations. Deleting and recreating the .m file fixed the error for me.