# Xcode error "Duplicate Symbol" causing Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: xcode, linker, mach-o

```
duplicate symbol _leagueTableLoaded in:
/Users/Brendan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/2013-dbhrwzgxgwhfbqatgqpfrmqyucyu/Build/Intermediates/2013.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/2013.build/Objects-normal/i386/LTGlobalResultsViewController.o

/Users/Brendan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/2013-dbhrwzgxgwhfbqatgqpfrmqyucyu/Build/Intermediates/2013.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/2013.build/Objects-normal/i386/LTJumpToMeViewController.o

duplicate symbol _showGLobalCompany in:

/Users/Brendan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/2013-dbhrwzgxgwhfbqatgqpfrmqyucyu/Build/Intermediates/2013.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/2013.build/Objects-normal/i386/LTGlobalResultsViewController.o

/Users/Brendan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/2013-dbhrwzgxgwhfbqatgqpfrmqyucyu/Build/Intermediates/2013.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/2013.build/Objects-normal/i386/LTJumpToPositionViewController.o

duplicate symbol _leagueTableLoaded in:

/Users/Brendan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/2013-dbhrwzgxgwhfbqatgqpfrmqyucyu/Build/Intermediates/2013.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/2013.build/Objects-normal/i386/LTGlobalResultsViewController.o

/Users/Brendan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/2013-dbhrwzgxgwhfbqatgqpfrmqyucyu/Build/Intermediates/2013.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/2013.build/Objects-normal/i386/LTJumpToPositionViewController.o

ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am getting the error above in xcode only when I try to build in simulator (on any iOS device I can build without error). I have three classes:

1.LTGlobalResultsViewController
2.LTJumpToMeViewController
3.LTJumpToPositionViewController

All three were created in xcode but both 2 & 3 have been modified outside of xcode and then rebuilt.

The @property bool leagueTableLoaded is defined in the header for all three. it is declared as:

```
@property bool leagueTableLoaded;
```

What is it exactly that is causing this error? I have tried the following:

1. I have tried renaming leagueTableLoaded in different classes but this doesn't fix it.
2. I have tried deleting my Derived Data files manually in library/developer/xcode folder.
3. According to other questions I have checked if I am importing a .m file. This is not the case. [Apple Mach-O Linker error ("duplicate symbol")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644927/apple-mach-o-linker-error-duplicate-symbol)

Any other suggestions or advice?
Thanks,
James

ADDITION: As requested please find all the extracts from my .h and .m files that reference leagueTableLoaded or any of the variants I created when trying to get round this error:

```
LTJumpToMeViewController.h
@property bool leagueTableLoadedMe;

LTJumpToMeViewController.m
@implementation LTJumpToMeViewController
bool leagueTableLoaded = false;

LTGlobalResultsViewController.h
@property bool globalLeagueTableLoaded;

LTGlobalResultsViewController.m
@implementation LTGlobalResultsViewController
bool leagueTableLoaded = false;

LTJumpToPositionViewController.h
@property bool leagueTableLoadedPos;

LTJumpToPositionViewController.m
@implementation LTJumpToPositionViewController
bool leagueTableLoaded = false;
```

I can provide more information if required!

Comment: Please show the header files declaring these properties (or at least one of them).

Comment: Updated in the question body. Thanks

Comment: That's still not enough to solve this problem.  Please go to the command prompt and change to your project directory and type `find . -type f -exec grep leagueTableLoaded {} \;` and post the output here.

Comment: Output is as follows:
bool leagueTableLoaded = false;
@ property bool leagueTableLoadedPos;
bool leagueTableLoaded = false;
    if ([self checkIfBonusSubmitted] == true && self.leagueTableLoadedPos == false)
        self.leagueTableLoadedPos = true;
bool leagueTableLoaded = false;
@ property bool leagueTableLoadedPos;
bool leagueTableLoaded = false;
    if ([self checkIfBonusSubmitted] == true && self.leagueTableLoadedPos == false)
        self.leagueTableLoadedPos = true;

Comment: any ideas on this please trojanfoe? Thanks, James

Comment: No, not without more info.  The output you provided from `find` didn't prove useful.  You'll need to post the relevant parts of the `.h` and `.m` file (relevant being bits relating to `leagueTableLoaded`).

Comment: updated in question as requested. Thanks

Comment: Are there any Frameworks you need (or forgot) to add to your project?

Comment: Wouldn't it then not compile? I can run it fine on my device just not on the simulator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this end this was being caused by the leagueTableLoaded bool being defined in both LTGlobalResultsViewController.m and LTJumpToPositionViewController.m.

Removing it from one of them fixed the issue. Although I'm not sure why it was there in the first place! Hope this helps anyone else who experiences the same issue! James

Answer (score 6):

For me a duplicate symbol error came up when I absent mindedly included a .m file instead of a .h (Why does Xcode's autosuggest even show me .m files?!)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode error “Duplicate Symbol” causing Apple Mach-O Linker Error is caused by duplicate symbols in Project. Steps to avoid error

1. **Go to project** ->  **Target** ->**Build Phases** ->**Compile sources**
2. **Check for the duplicate file (implementation file)**
3. **Delete the file and add it again**
4. **Clean and run project again**

This worked for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In second view controller, you mistakenly ***#import "First.m"***, check it must be *first.h* file so replaces this with *first.h*. It's working for me.