# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, mmrecord

I have tried all the answers available on stackoverflow but nothing seems to be working.

I get the following error whenever i create a (TCRecord)subclass of MMRecord.

Error:
`duplicate symbol _MMRecordErrorDomain in:
    /Users/mavericks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Beered-efrmoegppszsqtbcbtfrytgkdlyy/Build/Intermediates/Beered.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Beered.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TCRecord.o
    /Users/mavericks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Beered-efrmoegppszsqtbcbtfrytgkdlyy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-MMRecord.a(MMRecord.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Things i have already tried:

- Tried removing the -ObjC in other linker flags
- I have already checked the directory for any duplicate files
- Under Compile sources there is no duplication of implementation files.

Third party library i am using :
MMRecord
https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMRecord

Comment: cheek your file where you import  TCRecord and MMRecord ...is it .h file or .m file

Comment: When i create TCRecord which is a subclass of MMRecord, the MMRecord.h file is imported in TCRecord which is how it should be

Comment: ohh..its ok ...but this is the most common reason...accidentally put .m instead of .h ...

Comment: have u used coco pods in ur project ?

Comment: @SarathiOS Yes i am using cocoa pods

Comment: @rishabhbhatia used youtube integration ? most of the case u got the problem with any pod commands used in the project that may be outdated or being changed.

Comment: @SarathiOS No i am not using youtube integration. Ya i feel problem has something to do with the cocoa pods but not sure where to look

Comment: @rishabhbhatia did you figure this out yet? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @user2995344 , I have added the answer try that it worked for me.

Comment: See this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46726432/4140018) if above not working. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, in your project settings, search for "gcc_no" and set the flag to NO until we get the issue fixed. That should allow you to build your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting extra frameworks that have no use.

Comment: I have only added the frameworks which will be used in the project

Comment: TCRecord.o and MMRecord.o have something common. Which is generating this error. Like you have defined same things twice. Which is a conflict.

Comment: As the error says "duplicate symbol _MMRecordErrorDomain" , the constant MMRecordErrorDomain is defined in MMRecord. All  i did was created a subclass of MMRecord. There is no other code in TCRecord

Comment: You haven't added any methods that are related to C ?
It mainly causes the error, Like if you add the method for MAIN.